# Syncing calls and text from an old phone device to iphone live

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, sim, call

### Syncing calls and text from an old phone device to iPhone live

---

**Context:**

---

So I've got two sims: one which has a good data plan, and one which has a good texts/calls plan (i.e. on the first sim, I can't use calling or SMS, only imessage, messenger, whatsapp etc.). For my purposes, these two sims are not going to change i.e. don't tell me to get another sim.

The problem essentially is that both sims are physical, and my iPhone 12 Pro Max only supports one physical and one esim. Neither of my sims have esim capabilities, so currently I am unable to use both in my iPhone.

I also have an old iPhone lying around

---

**Question:**

---

> I was wondering, if I put one sim - the calling sim - into the old phone such that it will receive calls and texts, then can I sync all those calls and texts live to my iPhone 12 Pro Max? i.e. somehow use both sims on the 12 through linking a 2nd phone?

No idea if this is possible, but asking anyway.

---

**Thanks!**

---

Comment: Why not contact one of the providers & ask them to switch to an e-SIM. You don't pay for the SIM itself, just the "right to use the phone number".

Comment: My provider doesn't support e-Sim @Tetsujin, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: iCloud can sync messages for sure, and AFAIK also call history. I can't test with a second iPhone but you can use your Mac or iPad to receive incoming calls that go to your other iPhone, so I guess it should work for another iPhone as well but can't confirm it.

Comment: This looks like something you could just try to see what happens. If both phones are using the same AppleID, a lot of syncing should happen automatically. Enabling Handoff/Continuiity probably helps.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside and X_841. Will try.